# Total variation of $(x-[x])^2$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I am having trouble finding the total variation $V$ of the function $f(x) = (x-[x])^2$ on the interval $[0,b]$, where $[x]$ denotates the Greatest Integer function. I believe the maximum **positive** variation $P[f;0,b]$ will occur when the partition coincides with the integers $1,2,\ldots,b$ and in that case $P = b$, but I am not sure. Thanks in advance.
**EDIT:** My attempt:
For a general $b \in \mathbb{R}$ the maximum **positive** variation $P[f;0,b]$ will occur when the partition coincides with the integers $1,2,\ldots,[b]$, and in that case $P = [b]+(b-[b])^2$. Similarly, the maximum negative variation account the jumps on every integer $1,2,\ldots,[b]$ so $N= [b]$ . Since $V = P+N$ we have $V = 2[b]+(b-[b])^2$.

Comment: Your belief seems to be promising. Why don't you try to prove it?

Comment: Thanks. I think the positive variation would be $[b]+(b-[b])^2$  in the general case where $b$ is not an integer. Still, I am having trouble arguing that any other partition would generate a lesser variation of $f$.

Comment: You might have available lemmas that tell you what the total variation of a function is (1) on an interval on which the function is monotone, and (2) in a neighborhood of a jump discontinuity. Can you use those lemmas here, or adapt their proofs? (Side note: it's cool that your formula for the total variation simplifies to $b^2+[b]^2$.)

Comment: @bruceMath  draw a graph, and look at it for a few seconds. Your troubles will be over.

Comment: so is not $2[b]+(b-[b])^2$?. Sorry, I really can't see it. Thanks for your comments.